# Django Class-Based View: The view polls.views.ChoiceView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-views, httpresponse, django-class-based-views, detailview

I am new to django and I have created a function-based view which creates choices for a question.

```
def create_choice(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ChoiceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            choice = form.save(commit=False)
            choice.question = question
            choice.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(urlresolvers.reverse('polls:detail', kwargs={'question_id':question_id}))
    else:
        form = ChoiceForm()
    context = {'form':form, 'question':question}
    return render(request, 'polls/add_choice.html', context)
```

then I tried converting it into a class-based view...

```
class ChoiceView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'polls/add_choice.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ChoiceForm()
        question_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)

        context = {'form':form, 'question':question}
        return render(request, 'polls/add_choice.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            choice = form.save(commit=False)
            choice.question = question
            choice.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(urlresolvers.reverse('polls:detail', kwargs={'question_id':question_id}))
```

but when I runserver add a choice I get "The view polls.views.ChoiceView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." What did I do wrong? why do I not get a GET data?

Comment: The form might not be valid, in which case you are not returning anything which is `None`.

Comment: @Rohan I don't think so because when I purposely make the render to self.render_to_response to see what arguments are being pass on variable: form contains a valid form.ChoiceForm object. Only when I go to see the variable: response=None and in the variable: request I see this "GET:<QueryDict: {}>," which is an empty get

Comment: You cannot return `None` as a response from a Django view.

Comment: [See this part of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something). It specifically states that Django only requires one thing of views, and that is that views must return an HttpResponse with content or an exceptional response like Http404.

Comment: In you `def create_choice()` if form invalid you always return `render(request, 'polls/add_choice.html', context)` but in method post you return anything, but you should do it `return self.form_invalid(form)` and override `form_invalid` or just return there

Comment: and why do you need `DetailView` if you are doing everything manually? better read docs and after read docs again, but don't show such CBVs